# How to move lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, html-lists

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="li1">1</li>
<li id="li2">2</li>
<li id="li3">3</li>
</ul>
```

And I wonder if there is possible to move the list number 3, to the place of the list number 1 using javascript or jquery, like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="li3">3</li>
<li id="li2">2</li>
<li id="li1">1</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for you time!

Comment: -1 This isn't a good question, you're asking for a solution without saying anything about what you've tried.

Comment: `$('#li3').prependTo('ul'); $('#li1').appendTo('ul')`

Comment: If you're asking whether it's possible, the answer is clearly yes. Your HTML gets converted to a document object model (DOM). This is a tree structure of nodes, which can be modified as needed. In your example, there would be 3 `li` nodes that are children of the `ul` node. Those three nodes can be repositioned in such a matter as to reverse their order.

Comment: Thank u very much, at last I could do what I wanted, sorry but I cant vote for your answers yet =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jQuery solution :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    items = list.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    i = items.length;
while (i--) list.appendChild(items[i]);
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/tJaJ9/.

---

Based on cookie monster's suggestion :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    i = list.children.length;
while (i--) list.appendChild(list.children[i]);
```

---

Just for fun :

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    items = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.children);
while (items.length) list.appendChild(items.pop());
```

---

A jQuery one :

```
$('ul').append($('li').get().reverse());
```

Comment: Nice. +1 You could even drop the second line and use `list.children`. Your way has slightly better compatibility though. Either way, it's a short, fast solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ajax sortable jquery plugin**. One of my recommendation tutorial is [Sortable Lists Using jQuery UI](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/) . 
Here user can re-order list using cursor pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
var length = $('ul li').length;

while (length--) $('ul').append($('ul li')[length]);
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkNde/)